# HashTable in C not working for strings

Tags: c, pointers, hash, hashmap, hashtable

So I have been searching for **HashTable** implementations and I need my code to accept strings for input and not integers, like in most of the examples that have a key-value connection. I cannot figure out why the output is so weird. I cannot print the items with %s because I get a **Segmentation Fault(code dumped)** error, that's why I use %c inside **display()** function.

Source Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define SIZE 20
#define SEARCHKEY "10"

struct DataItem
{
   char value;   
   char key;
};

struct DataItem* hashArray[SIZE]; 
struct DataItem* dummyItem;
struct DataItem* item;

struct DataItem *get(char *key)
{
    int hashIndex = 0;      //get the hash 
    while(hashArray[hashIndex] != NULL)     //move in array until an empty 
    {    
        if(hashArray[hashIndex]->key == key)    return hashArray[hashIndex]; 
        ++hashIndex;        //go to next cell
        hashIndex %= SIZE;  //wrap around the table
    }        
    return NULL;        
}

void put(char *key,char *value)
{
    struct DataItem *item = (struct DataItem*) malloc(sizeof(struct DataItem));
    item->value = *value;  
    item->key = *key;
    int hashIndex = 0;  //get the hash
    bool condition = false;
    while(hashArray[hashIndex] != NULL && hashArray[hashIndex]->key != -1)  //move in array until an empty or deleted cell
    {
        if (hashArray[hashIndex]->key == item->key)
        {   
            condition = true;
            hashArray[hashIndex]->value = item->value;
        }
        ++hashIndex;        //go to next cell
        hashIndex %= SIZE;      //wrap around the table
    }
    if (condition == false) hashArray[hashIndex] = item;
}

void display() 
{
    int i = 0;
    printf("\n");
    for(i = 0; i<SIZE; i++) 
    {
        if(hashArray[i] != NULL)    printf("(%c,%c) ",hashArray[i]->key,hashArray[i]->value);
            else    printf(" ~~ ");
    }
    printf("\n\n");
}

int main() 
{
    dummyItem = (struct DataItem*) malloc(sizeof(struct DataItem));
    dummyItem->value = -1;  
    dummyItem->key = -1; 
    put("1", "20");
    put("2", "30");
    put("4", "40");
    put("8", "50");
    put("10", "60");
    put("10", "60");
    display();
    item = get(SEARCHKEY); // key search
    printf("Searching for key %s...\n", SEARCHKEY);
    if(item != NULL)    printf("Element found: %d\n", item->value);
        else        printf("No element found!!!\n");
}
```

Terminal Output:

```
$ gcc -o tcphash tcphash.c
tcphash.c: In function ‘get’:
tcphash.c:23:38: warning: comparison between pointer and integer
         if(hashArray[hashIndex]->key == key) return hashArray[hashIndex]; 
                                      ^
$ ./tcphash

(1,6) (2,3) (4,4) (8,5)  ~~  ~~  ~~  ~~  ~~  ~~  ~~  ~~  ~~  ~~  ~~  ~~  ~~  ~~  ~~  ~~ 

Searching for key 10...
No element found!!!
```

Comment: You need to compare strings with [`strcmp`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strcmp.3.html)

Comment: Your `DataItem` structure provides single-character `key` and `value` members.  Your code appears to handle those mostly consistently, but I don't think it's what you really want.  In any case, single characters certainly are not strings.

Comment: Pay heed to that compile warning.

Comment: using %s to print the values results in Segmentation Fault, thats why I used %c

Comment: `int hashIndex = 0;` Looks like linear search ...

Comment: 'using %s to print the values results in Segmentation Fault, thats why I used %c' - that's not a productive way of fixing problems.  If you are going to store the strings in that struct, you need to allocate space for the string in the struct, (directly or via malloc), and strcpy in the string, (or use strdup).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that - as mentioned by John Bollinger - your data structure stores single characters and not strings; therefore your functions store and print only the first character of your keys and values, respectively. Anyway, there are two issues:

First, replace `if(hashArray[hashIndex]->key == key)` with `if(hashArray[hashIndex]->key == *key)`. Otherwise you compare a character value with a pointer value, which will probably let the function select the wrong item or no item at all.

Second, replace `printf("Element found: %d\n", item->value)` with `printf("Element found: %c\n", item->value)`, because otherwise you would print a character value as an integer value (actually undefined behaviour, but likely to print the ascii code instead of the character).